# X509Chain Build failing on Alpine linux container in Azure Kubernetes Cluster with Istio

Tags: c#, linux, docker, x509certificate, azure-aks

I have a certificate which I am validating using X509Chain (`chain.Build(certificate)`). The certificate has an Intermediate CA X and a root Y, both of which are currently installed on my windows machine where I am testing.

On my windows machine, the chain.Build() succeeds (assuming because both the CAs are present on my machine), but the same validation code fails to validate the certificate on my linux container.

This is how my dockerfile looks like:

```
# pull down the build container
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-alpine3.10

WORKDIR /app

# expose ports
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 80

# Install cultures (same approach as Alpine SDK image)
RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs

# Disable the invariant mode (set in base image)
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false

# copy build output
COPY . /app

COPY ./Configuration/X.cer /usr/share/ca-certificates/X.crt
COPY ./Configuration/Y.cer /usr/share/ca-certificates/Y.crt

RUN echo "X.crt" >> /etc/ca-certificates.conf
RUN echo "Y.crt" >> /etc/ca-certificates.conf

RUN update-ca-certificates

# start the service
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ValidationService.dll"]
```

I have exported the base64 encoded X509 cert from my machine and using that to copy to /usr/share/ca-certificates/.
I make a manual entry into the ca-certificates.conf file in the etc folder and then run update-ca-certificates.
Post deployment, I see the correct entries in the conf file in my container, and also in the ssl folder, with my cert being added there. But my validation is still failing.

Not sure if I am missing any step here? Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of issues in your Dockerfile.

1. Try converting the certificate into a CRT format using OpenSSL:

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -in certificate.cer -out certificate.crt
```

2. Copy the certificates to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` path